# active record で JSON_CONTAINS で where を実行したい

Tags: ruby-on-rails, mysql, json, rails-activerecord

```
create table posts (
  id integer,
  tags json
);
```

上記のようなテーブルがあり、 tags には タグ(文字列) の配列が json として入っているとします。

```
mysql> select * from posts;
+------+-----------------+
| id   | tags            |
+------+-----------------+
|    1 | ["c++", "java"] |
|    2 | ["ruby"]        |
|    3 | ["c++"]         |
+------+-----------------+
```

たとえば、 c++ が入っている Post を取得するには、 sql においては、

```
select * from posts where JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '"c++"', '$');
```

を実行すればよいですが、これを active record 上からどうやったら実行できるのか、と思っています。

#### 質問

上記テーブルに対して、 Post モデルを次のように定義したとします。

```
class Post < ApplicationRecord
end
```

Post から、 c++ のタグが含まれる Relation を作成するにはどうしたらよいでしょうか?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
irb(main):015:0> Post.where("JSON_CONTAINS(tags, ?, '$')", 'c++'.to_json)                
  Post Load (0.8ms)  SELECT  `posts`.* FROM `posts` WHERE (JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '\"c++\"', '$')) LIMIT 11
=> #<ActiveRecord::Relation [#<Post id: 1, tags: ["c++", "java"]>, #<Post id: 3, tags: ["c++"]>]>
```

普通に where が書けるのですね。

Answer (score 1):

[`find_by_sql`で検索する](https://railsguides.jp/active_record_querying.html#sql%E3%81%A7%E6%A4%9C%E7%B4%A2%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) 方法で解決できると思います。

```
Post.find_by_sql(%Q{SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, '"c++"', '$')})
```

Comment: `Post.find_by_sql [%Q[SELECT * FROM POSTS WHERE JSON_CONTAINS(tags, :tags, '$')], tags: 'c++'.to_json]` でひとまずいけました。

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37300385/mysql-5-7-json-datatype-query-with-activerecord-in-rails-5?answertab=votes#tab-top の 回答にある方法でもいけるようです。環境がないので試せていませんが。